# Downloading large files with AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I'm trying to implement downloading of a large file and show to user current progress, but block in:

```
-[AFURLConnectionOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:]
```

returns incorrect `bytesRead` and `totalBytesRead` values (they are smaller than they should be).

For example: If I have a 90MB file and when it downloads completely, latest block invocation in `setDownloadProgressBlock:` gives me `totalBytesRead` value about 30MB. On other side, if file is 2MB large, latest block invocation gives correct `totalBytesRead` 2MB value.

AFNetworking is updated to the latest version from github.
If AFNetworking can't do it correctly, what solution can I use?

**Edit:** I've determined that even if file is not downloaded completely (and this happens every time with relatively big file) AFNetworking calls success block in:

```
-[AFHTTPRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]
```

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722436/afimagerequestoperation-returns-image-that-not-downloaded-competely) about this situation, but didn't get any answers.
I can check in code downloaded and real file sizes, but `AFNetworking` has no API for continuation of partial download.

Comment: Try out https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation it also supports resuming partial downloads

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have no problems with the setDownloadProgressBlock in AFNetworking.

The wiki explains how to track download progress:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ

For progress tracking you don't need the `bytesRead` (number of bytes written in a particular callback).

Example code:

```
[downloadoperation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        float progress = ((float)totalBytesRead) / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
        self.progressView.progress = progress;
    }];
```

Comment: Yes, I understand, my code is identical to yours. I'm only saying that bytesRead also gives incorrect  number on large files.

Comment: can you give an example? as I said you can ignore `bytesRead` because it is not relevant for progress.

Comment: what do you get with `NSLog(@"%u %llu %llu", bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead);`? bytesRead should be more or less the same value in each callback.

Comment: I've added an example to my question to clarify it. If I sum on every block invocation `bytesRead` it will give value equal to `totalBytesRead`, incorrect value in other words.

Comment: AFNetworking does it correctly, look at the source: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m#L542 Obviously the connection is cancelled too early, maybe because there is not enough disk space. I assume you have setup a NSOutputStream that writes to file. Otherwise you would consume very much memory and iOS may cancel the download because of that.

Comment: From the AFNetworking wiki: **How do I download a file?**
Use the outputStream property of AFURLConnectionOperation or its subclasses, setting it to an NSOutputStream that streams to a file at a specified path:

`operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:@"download.zip" append:NO];`
This is especially useful when you're downloading anything relatively large (more than a few MB), since the contents of the file will be streamed directly to the file, rather than being stored in memory.

Comment: I've used `outputStream`, but in some sense you are right, file is not downloaded completely to disk. I've updated my question, there are some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

**phix23 answered to my initial question, so there is really no problem with progress block. I'm answering to my edit.**

When success block in

```
-[AFHTTPRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]
```

is called, I can compare the number of bytes downloaded with the number of bytes expected to download (it is not very hard to implement in code). If the number of downloaded bytes is smaller - I can continue file download from place where it was interrupted. To do this, I'm using `Range` http header in `NSURLRequest`, here is more information:
[Continue an interrupted download on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975662/continue-an-interrupted-download-on-iphone)
[How to implement resumable file downloads on iPhone SDK](http://surgeworks.com/blog/lab-mobile/iphone/how-to-implement-resumable-file-downloads-on-iphone-sdk)

So, the problem is not really with AFNetworking (NSURLConnection has same behavior), but, I think, developers of the framework could take into account this situation.

Comment: ~goodfella "I can compare the number of bytes downloaded with the number of bytes expected to download. (it is not very hard to implement in code). "  Could you please elaborate in code?  How do you get number of bytes expected?  I am having trouble finding such an API from AFNetworking

Comment: You can find example code in the following class: https://github.com/onivem/Download, particularly in setCompletionBlocks method. Note that this class has been written for AFNetworking as it was on may 2013.